# Renovating session by sending new SMS MFA with Cognito and Amplify

Tags: reactjs, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I have a React app with Amplify that correctly sends SMS for user validation and authentication using the AWS Cognito pool.

The **Sign In** goes smoothly and the user gets the SMS.

The trouble arises when I try to implement a "Send new SMS" functionality for users that take too long to enter the OTP, and the session expires on them (3 min.).

The following is my normal sign in function:

```
async componentDidMount() {
  
    const username = "yyy";
    const password = "zzz";

    user = await Auth.signIn(username, password);

    const { challengeName } = user;

    console.log(user);

    if (!challengeName) {
        const { history } = this.props;
        history.push("/", { err: "No current user" });
    }
}
```

And this is my "Send new SMS" function:

```
resendConfirmationCode = async (e) => {
    
    try {
        await Auth.resendSignUp(this.state.username);
        console.log("code resent successfully");
        this.resetTimer();
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("error resending code: ", err);
    }
};
```

This does indeed send another SMS, but I will get the same error message with the first one that with the new one:

```
"NotAuthorizedException", message: "Invalid session for the user, session is expired."
```

I have also tried to refresh the session, and I get a new SMS, but it will result in the same error message:

```
testingSessionTwo = async (e) => {
    try {
        const cognitoUser = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
        const currentSession = cognitoUser.signInUserSession;
        cognitoUser.refreshSession(currentSession.refreshToken, (err, session) => {
            
            Auth.signOut();
            
            const username = "sss";
            const password = "xxx";

            Auth.signIn(username, password);
            console.log(session);
        });
    } catch (e) {
        // whatever
    }
};
```

What am I missing here?